# sql selectL rows to colums without subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, transpose

I have a table in Oracle 10g that contains some information as follows:

```
SQL> select * from t_test;

      INFO     CODIGO GRUPO
---------- ---------- ----------
       101        190 VTOS
       100        130 VTOS
       102        140 VTOS
```

I'd like to extract all the rows that have GRUPO='VTOS' and transpose those rows to columns. The values in CODIGO are predetermined(I know which values can be stored in that column), so would like to get something like this:

```
INFO_190 INFO_130 INFO_140
-------- -------- --------
     101      100      102
```

I know I can do it with some subqueries, for example:

```
SELECT (SELECT info
          FROM t_test
         WHERE codigo = 190 AND grupo = 'VTOS') info_190,
       (SELECT info
          FROM t_test
         WHERE codigo = 130 AND grupo = 'VTOS') info_130,
       (SELECT info
          FROM t_test
         WHERE codigo = 140 AND grupo = 'VTOS') info_140
  FROM DUAL
```

but I'd like to find a more efficient way. Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a relatively small number of codigo values, something like the following should work:

```
select max(decode(codigo, 190, info, '')) info_190,
 max(decode(codigo, 130, info, '')) info_130,
 max(decode(codigo, 140, info, '')) info_140
from t_test
where grupo = 'VTOS';
```

If you have multiple grupo values, group by grupo and include it in your select clause.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
select case CODIGO when 190 then INFO end AS INFO_190,
case CODIGO when 130 then INFO end AS INFO_130,
case CODIGO when 140 then INFO end AS INFO_140
from t_test where grupo = 'VTOS'
```