# Convert lines to columns in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

I would like to convert, by using a SQL-statement, the following table:

```
**Itemcode**   | **Number** | **Description**  
001            |  1         | blue
001            |  2         | M
002            |  1         | yellow
002            |  3         | Nike
003            |  1         | blue
003            |  2         | L
003            |  3         | Adidas
```

into

```
Itemcode       | 1      | 2         | 3                                 
001            | blue   | M         |
002            | yellow |           | Nike
003            | blue   | L         | Adidas
```

I tried using Pivot in my statement, but it didn't work. Who could help me?

Comment: There are tons os already answered questions same as this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql selectL rows to colums without subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085966/sql-selectl-rows-to-colums-without-subquery)

Comment: Could you add your pivot statement to your question?

Comment: Can you post your pivot statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregation` :

```
select code, 
       max(case when number = 1 then Description end) as one,
       max(case when number = 2 then Description end) as two,
       max(case when number = 3 then Description end) as three
from table t
group by code;
```